# How to create systemd.service in Fedora 16 (x86_64)?

Tags: fedora, service, systemd

I have big problem with creating service in new way - by systemctl (systemd.service) in Fedora 16.
I wonna to create very simple service for minidlna server. I have created new file called minidlna.service in /lib/systemd/system/ and here is how it's looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mini DLNA

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/minidlna

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Unfortunately systemctl status minidlna.service prints:

```
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/minidlna.service; enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead) since Sat, 03 Dec 2011 20:49:23 +0100; 9s ago
Main PID: 1580 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  CGroup: name=systemd:/system/minidlna.service
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Cheers!

Comment: In addition to the answer given, you may find [Fedora's systemd packaging guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works.

```
[Unit]
Description=Minidlna
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/minidlna -R -f /etc/minidlna.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```